# How do I make a singleton class without using private constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, singleton

Is there a way to make a class singleton without having a private constructor?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Is your question just out of interest? What would be the reason for not having a private constructor?

Comment: Simon- it's just for my interest .

Comment: With a `protected` constructor...

Comment: Jarod42 - implementation should be as : class should be singleton and constructor is public .

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can delete your constructor instead of making it private.

```
struct Widget{
  Widget()=delete;
};
```

**Advantages of a deleted constructor:**
The advantage of specifying a deleted constructor in place of a private deceleration, is that it will create a more intuitive error message when a user attempts to call it.  It can also be argued that it provides better intent to those who read your code.

**Advantages of a  private constructor:**
It will be compatible with older standards of the language, and have a wider range of compiler support.

Comment: how's possible to make singleton class in C++99 if constructor is public?

Comment: How to you create the singleton instance now that the constructor is deleted ?

Comment: @Jarod42 You would provide another public method that returns a pointer to an internally constructed object.

Comment: How do you construct object with deleted constructors ? And if you provide other public constructor, so you cannot guaranty singleton, that is my point.